# pair inside map - how to foreach

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have this code:

```
typedef std::map<const char *, std::pair<const char *, const char *> > MyMap;
MyMap the_map;

the_map.insert(std::make_pair("Text1", std::make_pair("Text2", "Text3")));
```

Obviously purpose is to store information in this way:

> "Text1" -> "Text2" -> "Text3"

Question: how do I foreach every element of the first key (eg "Text1") and change value of every inside key (eg "Text3").

Thank you.

Comment: That is not map inside map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an iterator of the map to go throw all elements:

```
for (std::map<const char *, std::pair<const char *, const char *> >::iterator ii = the_map.begin(), e = the_map.end(); ii != e; ii++) {
    // ii.first  - key value
    // ii.second - stored value (in your case a pair)
    //
    // ii.second.first  - key value of pair stored in map under ii.first
    // ii.second.second - stored value of pair stored in map under ii.first
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) does not have `begin()` or `end()` functions.

You only need one loop:

```
for (const auto& it : the_map) {
        std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second.first 
                  << " " << it.second.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I use too old GCC and get this error message: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'it' with no type [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Amanda vz_ provides an answer using iterators without the `auto` keyword.